# How can i test multiple java files with the same junit?

Tags: java, testing, junit

How can i test several .java files(that implements the same method in different ways) with one unit test?
For example, i have a folder with different .java files(or different folders with the same name .java file), how can i select all of them to run it?
right now i need to select each time one of them and move it to the same folder with the unit test and run it.
Thanks.

Edit: I think i wasn't clear enough, so i will give more example:

I have files aa.java and bb.java, which both have the method "static public int fibonacci(int x)", i want to create a unit test, that will use aa and bb methods and see if they work properly(assertEquals(result, expected)).
P.S. i have more then only 2 files with the same method.

Comment: You should start by describing your project structure. Maybe give us an example of a class you want to test and your corresponding unit test.

Comment: its pretty simple classes, they contain simple methods such as return the nth Fibonacci number and etc. 
static public int fibonacci(int x) {..} and my test of course will assert the outcome

Comment: there is no rule saying you have to test only one class one time. It is totally fine to test different implementation. What's your difficulties?

Comment: well.. my difficulties is that i don't know how to do it =] i mean, how can i select a folder that contain different java files and test on all of them the same test? ('in one click')

Comment: I think i wasn't clear enough, i want to test different java files that i got from scholars assignments, how can i do that with a single unit test without moving every time one file to the src folder

Comment: Generally, once you start with a more complex project you use a build tool like Maven or Gradle to coordinate all of this. In Eclipse, though, you can quite easily right-click on a folder full of tests (including up to the whole `src/test/java`) and select Run As... JUnit Test.

Comment: @chrylis I didn't tried eclipse yet, will try it, but what you said was the opposite of what i asked, i want to run 1 unit test, on a folder full of java classes

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to adhere to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), write a utility method to do the testing, and have a unit test(s) call it.

Eg

```
private static void assertFibonacci(IntUnaryOperator op) {
    int n = 5;
    int expected = 8;
    // or a loop of values, whatever
    assert op.applyAsInt(n) == expected;
}
```

Then in your unit test:

```
@Test
public void testX() {
    assertFibonacci(new aa()::fibonacci);
    assertFibonacci(new bb()::fibonacci);
}
```

Or better, use separate Test methods, so errors in each are reported separately:

```
@Test
public void testAA() {
    assertFibonacci(new aa()::fibonacci);
}

@Test
public void testBB() {
    assertFibonacci(new bb()::fibonacci);
}
```

Comment: hmm.. nice idea, is there a way to implement it when all my ".java" files are with the same name? (they are located in folders like this: 123/ex.java, 124/ex.java and etc.)

Comment: @neorus yes; fully qualify the class names: `assertFibonacci(new my.project.package1.aa()::fibonacci);`

Comment: This does what the OP asks but is a bad idea because the reporting will be useless.

Comment: @chrylis If you want separate errors for each, use different Test methods (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

The [Spock Framework](http://spockframework.org/), which runs on top of JUnit, has much better support for *parameterized testing*, which is what you seem to want, than either plain JUnit or TestNG.

If you can't use Spock, you can either use JUnit `Parameterized` and supply an instance of each of your classes as your data set, or (my recommendation) write all your common unit tests in an abstract base class `WidgetTests` with a method `protected abstract Widget getInstance()` and subclass for each kind of widget. This will still end up with multiple classes, but you won't repeat your test cases, and it allows you to write additional implementation-specific tests in an organized way.